# How configure nginx to give access to storage folder?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have the following nginx configuration that works fine. I have an API (Expressjs) on /api location and a Frontend Development (Vuejs) in /:

```
server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        root /var/www/domain.com/public_html;

        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        location /api {

                proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://example.com';
                proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
                proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-type,Origin';

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffering on;

                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        origin          'https://example.com';
        }
```

In my API I have a public folder (`public/storage/`) where I can store images. But when trying to access that folder I'm having 404 error. How can I configure my nginx server to giving access to the storage folder?

Comment: does "my api have a public folder" mean you would like to proxy the traffic to localhost:8080 or are you able to access the public files directly on disk like /var/www/domain.com/public/storage. Can you please share the NGINX error.log with the 404. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note when the request URI is:
`http://example.com/api/public/storage/image.jpg`

Then the request for the proxy will be the same as well. e.g

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/public/storage/image.jpg`

If you would like to change that, you should add URI to the directive `proxy_pass` itself. e.g

`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/;`.

which will map requests to :

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/public/storage/image.jpg`

(there is double `public` intentionally.)

Comment: Thank you @JonnieJS !